# CSS: Align N divs horizontally in a wrapper

Tags: html, css

How can I achieved aligning of N contiguous `divs` horizontally with a wrapper whose `width` is 'auto'?

like:

```
.boxes{ width:200px;height:200px;float:left; }

<div id="wrapper" style="width:auto;">
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    <div class="boxes"></div>
    . . .
</div>
```

I tried applying `display:inline;` and `display:inline-block;` on wrapper but **boxes** goes into new y after it reaches the browsers/display width?

But setting document's width into fixed will solve the issue but its not what I want.

Also I can easily achieved this using `tables` but I don't want to do it because my code will look messy and will be hard for me to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#wrapper
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and on your boxes class: change `float:left` to `display:inline-block;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PXSJ2/1/)**

This will keep your boxes from wrapping.

Comment: Why is it not working in my browser. I just copy-pasted your code and not working

Comment: Yep but not in my browser

Comment: Which browser are you using...or which browser doesn't work and which browser works?

Comment: The same in firefox and chrome..still having trouble to run this on IE

Comment: white-space: nowrap; - is supported by IE 5.5+ so there shouldn't be any problems here - see http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/